# Count elements containing less than 3 consecutive zeros within vector in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

For example, I have the following vector:

```
A = [34 35 36 0 78 79 0 0 0 80 81 82 84 85 86 102 0 0 0 103 104 105 106 0 0 107 201 0 202 203 204];
```

Each element within A represents a value at every second. I want to count the elements containing less than 3 consecutive zeros in A => I will obtain duration values in seconds for A.

In this case, the counting stops before every 3 consecutive zeros and starts over after the 3 consecutive zeros, and so on. It's like this:

```
A = [34->1s 35->2s 36->3s 0->4s 78->5s 79->6s stop 80->1s 81->2s 82->3s 84->4s 85->5s 86->6s 102->7s stop 103->1s 104->2s 105->3s 106->4s 0->5s 0->6s 107->7s 201->8s 0->9s 202->10s 203->11s 204->12s];
```

The result would like this:

```
Duration = [6 7 12]; in seconds
```

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: Please explain how you got 6, 7 and 12 as your result.  I don't see the correlation between that output and your array.

Comment: I edited it. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: @Bowecho are you only looking for `Duration`? What happens if there are no 2s, 3s or 4s but there are 5s?

Comment: @Dan Each element within A is computed every second. So, for the elements `34, 35, 36, etc` I have `second 1, second 2, second 3, etc`. This is what I was referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `A` to characters `'0'` and `'1'` (for example) depending on whether the original value is zero or nonzero, use `strsplit` and then obtain the number of elements of each substring.

Let `N = 3` be the number of zeros for splitting. Then:

```
Duration = cellfun(@numel, strsplit(char((A>0)+'0'), repmat('0',1,N)));
```

Note that the above code does the splitting based on **exactly `N`** zeros. For example, `A = [1 2 3 0 0 0 0 4 5]` gives `Duration = [3 3]`, because the fourth zero is assigned to the second substring.

If you want to split based on **`N` or more** zeros, use a regular expression:

```
Duration = cellfun(@numel, regexp(char((A>0)+'0'), [repmat('0',1,N) '+'], 'split'));
```

For `A = [1 2 3 0 0 0 0 4 5]` this gives `Duration = [3 2]`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Very good one-line answer. Thanks

Comment: I've included a `regexp`-based approach in case you want to split based on three _or more_ zeros

Answer (score 3):

One approach with [`convolution`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) -

```
%// Input
A = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 34 35 36 0 78 79 0 0 0 ...
    80 81 82 84 85 86 102 0 0 0 103 104 105 106 0 0 107 201 0 202 203 204];

%// Mask with all >= groups of three consecutive 0's set at 0's, 1's elsewhere 
M = conv(double(conv(double(A==0),ones(1,3),'same')>=3),ones(1,3),'same')==0

%// Append with 0's to get their indices in the next step
dfd = diff([0 M 0])

%// Get indices for falling and rising edges and subtract them for Duration
Duration = find(dfd==-1) - find(dfd==1)
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
  Columns 1 through 14
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    34    35    36     0    78    79     0
  Columns 15 through 28
     0     0    80    81    82    84    85    86   102     0     0     0   103   104
  Columns 29 through 38
   105   106     0     0   107   201     0   202   203   204
>> M
M =
  Columns 1 through 14
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
  Columns 15 through 28
     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1
  Columns 29 through 38
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
>> Duration
Duration =
     6     7    12
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another vectorized `conv` based alternative:

```
Duration = diff([0,find(~conv(A, ones(1,3))),numel(A)+3])-3
```

Comment: It's also successful. Thanks

Comment: For the example given above by @Luis Mendo, considering `A = [1 2 3 0 0 0 0 4 5]` gives `Duration = [3 -2 2]` instead of `Duration = [3 2]` with this code.

Comment: @Bowecho if that is a case to consider, then you need to redefine your question. I also asked you what to do about a case like `A = [34->1s 0->2s 0->3s 0->4s 78->5s 79->6s stop ...`?

Comment: That would look like `A = [34->1s stop 78->1s 79->2s stop ...]` I didn't understand well what were you referring to, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [34 35 36 0 78 79 0 0 0 80 81 82 84 85 86 102 0 0 0 103 104 105 106 0 0 107 201 0 202 203 204];
count=0;
count2=0;
Duration = [];
for i=1:(size(A,2)-3)
count2=count2+1;
if(A(1,i+1)==0)
    count=count+1;
    if(A(1,i+2)==0)
        count=count+1;
    else
        count=0;
    end
    if(A(1,i+3)==0)
        count=count+1;
    else
        count=0;
    end
    if(count==3)
        Duration = [Duration,count2 ];
        count2=-3;

         end
       else
    count=0;
     end
     end
        Duration = [Duration,count2+3 ];

    Duration
```

The code detects 3 consecutive zeros,  a second counter keeps track of the duration. I hope this helps.

Comment: The result I get is not correct. I get `Duration = [7    17    25]` instead of `Duration = [6 7 12]`.

Comment: The code is to detect 3 consecutive zeros. Set another counter which resets when count=3. I assume that will give you what you need

Comment: I didn't understand your question at first and assumed this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you wander over to Fileexchange and grab  [seqle](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36955-sequence-length-encoder--seqle--similar-to-rle-) , you can use this to extract all runs of zero and non-zero elements, thus simplifying your search.